# True difference between pageContext.getSession().setAttribute() and pageContext.setAttribute()

Tags: java, jsp

I have been going crazy about resetting some validation error on one of my jsp pages. This is a project inherited from people I cannot reach anymore (dead or unavailable). I have a jsp page with lots of custom taglibs where further pages are added as tabs and the parent page has action buttons to open things like forms. There is a validation error and some configuration parameter being set/modified both in the tabs section and the parent page. But the interesting thing is that I can see the heavy use of `pageContext.setAttribute()`, `session.setAttribute()` and `pageContext.getSession().setAttribute()`. If my initial knowledge is right, `pageContext` is quite heavily used in servlet-based implementations. but how different things would be if I use those following three on my JSp pages to set attributes?

** Example Scenario (my problem): **

I have some attributes set in the parent page, which are also being set/modifed in the tabs page (embedded in the parent page). I want to remove them such that if there is a validation error, I will simply remove what I have in the tabs page i.e. next time the page will simply load those attributes from the parent page. Do I use `pageContext.setAttribute()` in the tabs page, but use `pageContext.getSession().setAttribute()` in the parent page?

KR,

Comment: The first one sets a page attribute, the other two are equivalent and set a session attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Page scope**

When we put in our `JSP` page, scope is available only for the `JSP` page that put it. 
This is the default scope, so is the same to call `pageContext.setAttribute("", "", PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);` same as `pageContext.setAttribute("", "");`

**Session scope**
`session.setAttribute()` and `pageContext.getSession().setAttribute()` both are same.
What you put on your session scope is available across all requests on the same user session.
Is the same to call `pageContext.setAttribute("", "", PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);` same as `session.setAttribute("", "");`